# How to double click on a map element in a web page?

Tags: selenium

I will able to double click on a web element but i can't double click on **a map** in a web page. It might be a [Embedded Rescourse.](https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/components/components-embedded.html) so how can i make mouse double click on element like this one. I can make click only but can't double click so is there any way to do that manualy with only single clicks.

`actions.doubleClick(WebElement)` --> Doesn't work

---

```
Actions actions = new Actions(getDriver());
actions.moveByOffset(700,700);
actions.click().build().perform();
```

---

This one works but only single click not a double.

Comment: ìs that Map Component is in frame?

Comment: Can you share the relevant `HTML` or the `URL` along with your Manual Steps you are trying to `Automate`?

Comment: <div class : esriMapContainer   .... >